# Angular 6 router in wordpress plugin does not work in refresh

Tags: wordpress, angular, .htaccess, angular2-routing

I am making a wordpress plugin which is actually an Angular 6 javascript app. I have following codes to make it work as short code in wordpress

```
function msp_helloworld_load(){
    ob_start();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/runtime.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/polyfills.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script2', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/styles.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script3', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/vendor.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script4', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/main.js' );    
    echo '<base href="' . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] . '">';
    echo '<app-root></app-root>';
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'msp_helloworld_load' );
```

In this app I am using a simple Angular 6 router like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact',      component: ContactComponent }
];
```

I am embedding this short code in sample-page of wordpress as

```
[helloworld]
```

Which is rendering good and router is working while I am clicking in it. The two urls look like this

http://localhost/wp/sample-page

http://localhost/wp/sample-page/contact

Problem occurs when I am reloading the page. It does not find anything.

My .htaccess looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hn/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hn/index.php [N]    
RewriteRule ^ /sample-page/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But still its not working. I am no good with the .htaccess so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Great I have worked it out. Here is the solution first you dont have to touch the .htaccess as it comes with default wordpress installation

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hn/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hn/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then change the wordpress permalink as postname

Then here is the trick, on the base tag point the page you want to embed the short code. You can accept parameter from the user to point the base url from the content entry or you can even make it dynamic to put the page url. That's it.

```
function msp_helloworld_load(){
    ob_start();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/runtime.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/polyfills.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script2', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/styles.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script3', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/vendor.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script4', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app/main.js' );    
    echo '<base href="http://localhost/wp/sample-page/">';
    echo '<app-root></app-root>';
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'msp_helloworld_load' );
```

Also add a custom url rewrite

```
function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {  
    add_rewrite_rule( '^sample-page/([^/]*)/?', 'sample-page?city=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: Hello Dave.
I have the same problem as you. I´m trying to understand how you solved it rewriting the url to a querystring (sample-page?city=$matches[1]).
You did something special in your angular app to resolve querystring?

Thank you

Comment: No I have not made any spacial config in angular side. This works still now.  (sample-page?city=$matches[1]) is just an example I have mentioned here.

Comment: ok, my problem was that I wasn´t writing the rewrite_rule well. Thank you